# POST request to a friendly URL fails

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I'm trying to post an HTTP request to an HTML form that is accessible through the friendly URL address.
But when I post it, library returns error code "bad URL provided".

```
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConn, L"POST", L"newform",
                     NULL, L"http://www.example.com/add/newform/",
                     rgpszAcceptTypes, NULL, NULL);
DWORD error_code   = GetLastError();
bool hResult       = HttpSendRequestW(hRequest,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
error_code         = GetLastError(); //12005 - bad URL provided
```

What am I doing wrong, why does my request fails?

Comment: Please use full english words.

Comment: "thru" that I corrected earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server name (www.site.com in your above example) must be specified in the call to InternetConnect, as must the protocol (INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP).

In the call to HttpOpenRequest you only give the name of the "object", which in this case is "/add/newform/".

For example (added for more clarity):

```
HINTERNET hConn = InternetConnect(hInternet, L"www.site.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
    NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConn, L"POST", L"/add/newform", NULL, NULL,
    rgpszAcceptTypes, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Why not? Did you at least look at the docs for the functions I mentioned?

Comment: Ok, well it didn't look like you quite understood them. I've added an example to my answer which might make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I've made exactly like this, and it still saying that i got wrong URL. I already dropdown my WinInet code and switched to a WinHTTP library. The main problem that I can't see what WinInet or WinHttp are directly sending to a server. I mean headers, data, and stuff like that.

Comment: I need to create a full-fledget POST request to a page, with all form data (which is multipart) and stuff

Comment: You might want to look at rephrasing your question with more detail, showing more of your code in that case.